# Counting the number of linearly independent Killing vectors for some $N$-dimensional geometry of space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields

In symmetric spaces(for spacetimes of Einsteinian General Relativity) we would like to find the vector space of Killing vectors($\xi^{(n)}_\mu(x)$) for the given metric tensor($g_{\mu\nu})$ at some fixed point $X$.

Now, for infinitesimal coordinate transformations(of the form $x'^\mu=x^\mu +\epsilon\xi^\mu(x) $) which is really a very special case, we determine the corresponding isometries in terms of the associated Killing vector fields.
This special case yields an interesting result about the *form of the Killing vector field, especially its possible degrees of freedom in terms of initial values of the field and its first order covariant derivative*.

For an infinitesimal patch about a fixed point $X$, the **approximate functional form of the $n$-th Killing vector field** looks like:
$$ \xi^{(n)}_\rho(x)= A^\lambda_\rho(x;X)\xi^{(n)}_\lambda(X)+B^{\lambda\nu}_\rho(x;X)\xi^{(n)}_{\lambda;\nu}(X)$$
Here $A^\lambda_\rho$ and $B^{\lambda\nu}_\rho$ are functions that depend on $g_{\mu\nu}$ and X and are essentially constants for the set of all Killing vector fields about a point $X$.
So, now the argument goes as follows.  :
$$\rm No.\,of\, independent\, killing \,vectors=No.\,of\,independent \,parameters\,uniquely\, identifying \,a\,Killing\,vector\,field\\ =N+\dbinom{N}{2}=\dbinom{N+1}{2} $$ 
Here, $N$=No. of independent initial values $\xi^{(n)}(X)$ and $\dbinom{N}{2}$=No. of independent initial values of covariant derivatives $\xi^{(n)}_{\lambda;\nu}(X)$(because of antisymmetry condition $\xi_{\sigma;\rho}=-\xi_{\rho;\sigma}$)

So, the question is: Is **this approximate calculation(involving Taylor series expansion of Killing vector field components about some fixed point $X$)** 
correct?

**It's disturbing to see that approximate methods are being used to yield very concrete answers like maximal number of independent Killing vectors in a vector space.**

*These arguments and line of reasoning are mostly drawn from Weinberg's book on Gravitation and Cosmology*.

Comment: It's quite possible to use approximate methods in a completely rigorous proof. I think to make this rigorous you need something like the fact (given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field)) that "A Killing field is determined uniquely by a vector at some point and its gradient (i.e. all covariant derivatives of the field at the point)." I have no idea if Weinberg used something similar in his argument, so I can't say whether it is completely rigorous.

Comment: Yes, you are right in that the initial conditions are just the values of the Killing vector field  components and its covariant derivatives  at X.  He does establish this quite early. Only, working with infinitesimal seems to be the trick that does the job but spoils the fun(the conditions become loose as first order correction terms are the only ones retained in the expansion).

Comment: It's a general principle that the structure of a Lie group is mostly contained in its Lie algebra, which is the first order transformations. ("Infinitesimal rotations" and such in physics speak.) The reason for this is that the flow of the vector fields preserve the group structure. Thus if the first order approximation is good enough in a radius $r$, you can do a new first order expansion around $r-\epsilon$ and get almost twice as far. In the physical example of Killing vectors we can be more concrete. The Killing vector generates a symmetry, so the spacetime looks the same at the point the

Comment: first order flow takes you to. Thus the first order approximation is good there, too!

Comment: Hey, could you suggest to me some references to understand these ideas better. I am a beginner so to speak.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you mean to say that sequential run of infinitesimal first order transformations can be good enough for a an overall non-infinitesimal interval. I had the idea that errors will add up very badly  in this scenario, as the no. of steps increase to infinity with neighborhood size shrinking almost to zero.

Comment: If what we were talking about were an arbitrary function, your doubts would be justified. But it's not; we're talking about a manifold with a group (that generates the Killing field) acting on it. That adds much more structure, and lets the value at one point determine the value everywhere. Offhand, I don't know any easy references for this. Maybe somebody else does.

Comment: Because the group structure is preserved, the error bound stays the same at the new point, so if $(1+cg)$ has an error bounded by $C\epsilon^2$, where $c < \epsilon$, then $(1+cg/n)^n$ has an error bounded by $Cn(\epsilon/n)^2  = C\epsilon^2/n $. This goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so all transformations can be built from first order ones. Note that for numbers $(1+tx/n)^n \to e^{tx}$ so the map between Lie algebra and Lie group is accordingly called the exponential map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory) and I think the best source for you would be a textbook on Lie

Comment: theory since that would certainly deal with the exponential map. Maybe this short article https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0005032 based on the author's book https://www.amazon.com/Lie-Groups-Algebras-Representations-Introduction/dp/1441923136 The expressions above and the name exponential map also come about because something similar to the differential equation $y' = ky$ satisfied by $e^{kx}$ shows up -- but to explain all of this in detail really well does require a book chapter-length exposition.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your valuable comments. I have heard of Lie groups and Lie algebra but I have not taken any formal course in it nor have read it. I will go through the references you have given. However, I am curious why Lie group theory comes into picture here. If you could explain..

Comment: It's because what we study with Killing vectors is what relativists call *continuous symmetries*: symmetries that can be parametrized by some finite set of parameters. For example, on the sphere, we have the rotation group which can be parametrized by the Euler angles. This is the characterization of a Lie group. Now if you look at how one goes from parametrized symmetries to Killing vectors, the Killing vector is basically the derivative of the symmetry. The Lie algebra of a Lie group is similarly defined in terms of derivatives on the group. Why is it like that? Well, what is the derivative?

Comment: The derivative is the infinitesimal linear approximation to a curve, the tangent. The Killing vector is tangent to how the symmetry moves points. So similarly, infinitesimal transformation are given in terms derivatives of of finite ones.

Comment: So enlightening, really!  Thanks again. I was wondering about another thing. These infinitesimal coordinate transformation are nothing but a **mere relabelling of coordinates of a patch into the coordinates of a neighboring patch**. The coordinate transformation derivative gives the Killing vector field, **iff** the space is symmetric as in the *metric tensor's functional form remains invariant*.

Comment: So if I am guessing right, this seems much like the *connection coefficient of differential geometry*, where the disconnected tangent spaces are connected by a kind of derivative viz.  the connection coefficient. In the case of Killing vectors, the symmetry/isometry is the enabler to define the derivative i.e. the Killing vector that connects the the points with identical local geometry.

Answer (score -1):

It is not any approximate answer . If you know the value of all derivatives at some point , you can write the function in terms of them . This is not any approximation.

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$...

Comment: You assume analyticity with this statement, which is untenable in reality.